# FBO and mipmap textures

Tags: opengl

Is it possible to attach a texture to an FBO which has mipmaps? 
I am currently trying to do this.I have a texture with several mipmap levels. I am attaching it to an FBO. When I clear the color for this buffer I still see the original texture in the output. Once I attach another texture with 1 mipmap level only the FBO draws the results correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though it's hard to say where your problem lies without any code, the fast and easy answer is just: Of course this is possible! Ever wondered what the `level` parameter of all those [`glFramebufferTexture` functions](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glFramebufferTexture.xhtml) is for?

But you can only write to a single mipmap level of the respective texture, all the other levels will be unchanged. The usual way is to write into mipmap level 0 (as you would do for a non-mipmapped texture) and generate the remaining levels by means of [`glGenerateMipmap`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGenerateMipmap.xhtml). But you can also write to any other level or to each and every level individually.

Comment: That is what I am trying now.Should I cal glFrameBufferTexture2D for each level?

Comment: @MichaelIV It depends. You can write to each level individually. But if the higher levels are just lower resultion versions of level 0 (which is usually the case for mipmapped textures), then that would be quite a stupid idea and you can just do a `glGenerateMipmap` to automatically generate them by downsampling the first level.

Comment: if I set level = 0 nothing changed if I clear color.if I set level =1 I can see the clearing color but with the next miplevel behind it...

Comment: @MichaelIV Like said, the FBO can only write into a single level, the other levels will of course just stay unchanged. As a general advice, you might really profit from a thorough and complete OpenGL learning resource, as evident by the many arbitrary assumptions you pose about OpenGL behaviour and the general trial-and-error nature of some of your questions.

Comment: Well,now I managed to get it working.Clear color and then generate mipmaps.Great,thanks.

Comment: @MichaelIV If you just want to clear all levels and not fill them with more complex data, then indidually clearing each level might even be faster than using `glGenerateMipmap` (which always does some kind of downfiltering, no matter if the texture has just a single color), given that `glClear` is likely to be extremely fast.

Comment: That's what I didn't find how to do.

Comment: @MichaelIV Just repeatedly attach a mipmap level to the framebuffer (using `glFramebufferTexture`'s obvious `level` parameter) and `glClear`, and repeat for each and every mipmap level.